# How do I access flash messages in zend framework, in IE?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using this in my layout file
$flash_messages = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages();

It works correctly in all browsers, except IE.  The array is empty in IE.  I confirmed that the messages are being set correctly, and are accessed correctly in other browsers.  It is just not working in IE.

Edit: I think I spoke too soon.  The messages are not even getting set, and this is the line I am using (though this line gets executed)

$this->_helper->FlashMessenger('my message here...');

Answer (score 2):

Hmm wierd, first time of my life i hear that something that is *server side* behaves differently in different browsers..

- It could be a session problem, check your IE accepts all cookies.
- It could be a css problem, check that your message isn't just hidden by incompatible css rules

And i believe it's :

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger')->setMessage('my message');
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaah...it works for others, just doesn't work on my IE.  Still trying to figure out what the prob is, it is definitely not my code

Comment: ok, got the issue.  I am using virtual hosts, it isn't working in IE.  if I access it using my IP, it works.  weird.  At least, I know now nothing is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Flash messages are just like sessions but with lifetime of 1 hop only . i.e first request will store the data , in second request you can access the data but in third you will get empty data . I think in IE you are jumping to third request or missing the first request itself (the time to store data) .